# Android 7 with targetSDK 22 Security vulnerability

Tags: target-sdk

Any know vulnerability with targetSDK 22?
I was using targetSDK 22 with Android 5.1, since there are no more security updates release by googles for Android 5.1. 
I just upgrade to my Android to 7? Will it address all my vulnerability as OS 7 will have latest security updates?

Answer (score 0):

You should target the latest sdk available. You can keep your min sdk low but the target should be always updated.